# Formatting XmlGregorianCalendar timezone issue

Tags: java, date, timezone, format

I need to format java XmlGregorianCalendar to "yyMMdd" string.
My implementation:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar date = getDate(); //getting the date

if (date != null) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");

        LOG.debug("Parsing date...");
        LOG.debug("XML Date: " + date);
        LOG.debug("XML Date timezone: " + date.getTimezone());

        GregorianCalendar gc = date.toGregorianCalendar();

        LOG.debug("Gregorian calendar: " + gc.toString());
        LOG.debug("Gregorian calendar timezone id: " + gc.getTimeZone().getID());

        Date d = gc.getTime();

        LOG.debug("Date: " + d.toString());

        String formatted = sdf.format(d);

        LOG.debug("Formatted: " + formatted);
}
```

What I see in log:

```
Parsing date...
XML Date: 1943-04-15T00:00:00.000Z
XML Date timezone: 0
Gregorian calendar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+00:00",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=1943,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=15,DAY_OF_YEAR=1,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
Gregorian calendar timezone id: GMT+00:00
Date: Wed Apr 14 20:00:00 EDT 1943
Formatted: 430414
```

April, 15 was parsed as April, 14. What I'm doing wrong? When I should set timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was parsed as midnight on April 15th *UTC*. It was then formatted as 8pm on April 14th *EDT*, which is correct as EDT is four hours behind UTC.

Note that `Date.toString()` always uses the *local* time zone - a `Date` object has no concept of which time zone it's in.

Your formatted value is *also* using the default time zone, as you haven't specified a time zone. The calendar value (`gc`) is in UTC, but when you format it, it will apply the time zone from the formatter (as you format the `Date` value, which doesn't *have* a time zone).

It's not clear what you were trying to achieve, but hopefully that will help. As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead if you possibly can - it makes a lot of this much clearer.

Comment: I was trying to parse it with timezone from XmlCalendar. Now I understood that I should set timezone to my formatter. Thanks for explanation.