# create XMLGregorianCalendar from String with yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00 time in java

Tags: java, xml, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I have a problem I need create XMLGregorianCalendar from String like “07.04.2015” with time 00:00:00 in general, for example like is 2015-04-07T00:00:00 what I am doing for this

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar getF(String stringDate) {
    XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = null;
    String formatedData = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat in_data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat out_data = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = in_data.parse(stringDate);
        formatedData = out_data.format(date);
        String df = formatedData;
        xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(df);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return xgc;

}
```

this code works correctly some results

```
getF("2015-04-07") -> 2015-04-07T00:00:00
getF("2015-04-07 14:40:49") -> 2015-04-07T00:00:00
```

however, sometimes this method returns `2015-04-07T01:00:00`
I don't know why the time is `01:00:00` time, and not `00:00:00`

Comment: Can you give an example of when 01:00:00 is added? Why don't you specifiy the time zone you are interested in?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241229/formatting-xmlgregoriancalendar-timezone-issue

Comment: Maybe something to do with DST?

Comment: if I knew about it wich stringDate adds 01:00:00, I did not ask this question :))

Comment: I know that server timezone is UTC +3:00, client timezone is UTC +5:00